# Woocommerce Empty Cart Issue with Request a Quote plugin and Woocommerce sample

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using woocommerce with Request a quote plugin and Woocommerce Sample with Porto theme.

Now the issue is When I add product to cart it shows successfully message but it is not visiable in cart.

Currently I have price for the product and set as In stock. But still after adding product to cart it always shows me empty cart.

For trouble shooting I have taken all the below mentioned steps:-

Changes Theme
Deactivated all the plugin
Removed Cache Plugin
Updated wordpress to latest version
Set htaccess file to default and reset the permalink.

```
Visit this link to see an issue 

https://b2cpjm57.myraidbox.de/produkte/test-product-1/

https://b2cpjm57.myraidbox.de/produkte/test-product-2/

https://b2cpjm57.myraidbox.de/produkte/test-product-3/
```

I am adding here the link of product which is having issue.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_TRUE');
function cw_remove_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_sold_individually','cw_remove_quantity_fields'
, 10, 2 );
```

Please try to add in cart but it will show you empty cart.

Any help in this much appreciated in advance.

I am struggling to resolve this issue for last 3 days but no luck.

And I am using this filter also in my child theme when product has no price and quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks who ever seen this post.

After all trying with basic troubleshooting issue didn't resolved.

I had completely deleted the woo commerce and re install a fresh setup.

After that it's started working fine.

Please have backup of your woo commerce data before uninstalling it completely.